# Rails Helper VS partial give different result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, helper

I have partial:

```
<% if title_top.any? %>
    <% title_top.each do |country| %>
        <li><%= link_to country.title, country%></li>
    <% end %>
    <li class="divider"></li>
<% end %>
```

it`s working fine and generate list tags with links, but I want to replace it with helper:

```
def link_to_list(var)
  if var.any?
    var.each do |country|
      content_tag :li do
        link_to(country.title, country)
       if var.first.top?
        content_tag(:li, class: "divider")
       end    
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Country array for argument:

```
def title_top
   @country_top = Country.where(top: true)
end
```

And helper doesn`t work, in console it give me:

```
ArgumentError: arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation
```

Where I am wrong, please help...I can leave it with partial, but my brain soon blow up because I can`t find right solution

**Thanks juanpastas**,
For me right answer is:

```
def link_to_list(var)
out = ''
devider ="<li class='divider'></li>" #divider for bootstrap menu
  var.each do |country|
    out += content_tag :li do        #list item with links inside 
       link_to country.title, country
    end
  end
   var.first.top ? (out << devider).html_safe  : out.html_safe #divide upper menu links from other links
end
```

(but I still can't understand why previous methods didn't worked)

Comment: you could print country in each block, maybe you have a nil?

Comment: another thing, I think you have to return all value in content_tag, I am going to write it as an answer, is not an answer though.

Comment: because I am not sure about it.

Comment: The error you're getting means that you're trying to use your helper somewhere where routes are not available, so your `country` objects can't be used as resources for route generation purposes. Can you provide more detail (where exactly you're defining the helper, how you're using it etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I meant in my comment

```
out = ''
var.each do |country|
  out += content_tag :li do
    out1 = link_to 'blah', 'route'
    if something
      out1 += content_tag :li
    end
    out1
  end
end
out
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a helper method using a route helper from the console, you should do:

```
irb(main):006:0* include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
=> Object
irb(main):007:0> ApplicationController.helpers.bogus(Thing.first)
  Thing Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "things".* FROM "things" LIMIT 1
=> "<li><a href=\"/things/2\">Thing</a></li>"
```

Next, your helper as it is won't give you what you want. As juanpastas said above, you need to concatenate the output of `content_tag`. I'd do it this way (note this is equivalent to your initial partial code, not the helper):

```
def link_to_list(list)
  html = ""
  unless list.empty?
    html += list.map { |item| content_tag(:li, link_to(item.title, item)) }.join.html_safe
    html += content_tag(:li, :class => "divider")
  end
  html
end
```